# create multiple text files of variable name using for loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have an array `$array_file_names` that contains 50 elements which are the names of the text files I wish to create. But the name of the file The code I have written is written below:

```
for($i=0;$i<$total_file_count;$i++)
{
    $file="$array_file_names[$i].txt";
    file_put_contents($file, "Testing....");
}
```

But the files that is created has the name `$array_file_names[$i]` and not the one that is contained in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
for($i=0;$i<$total_file_count;$i++)
{
  $file=$array_file_names[$i].".txt";
  file_put_contents($file, "Testing....");
}
```

Using variables inside double quoted strings is tricky sometimes, specially with arrays, and lead to strange bugs. I prefer the old fashioned concatenation.

And a cleaner way to writing this is using `foreach`:

```
foreach($array_file_names as $file_name)
{
  file_put_contents($file_name.".txt", "Testing....");
}
```

Comment: I have tried both the codes but the files are now not getting created.

Comment: @NamanArora, then do a `print_r($array_file_name);` and show us the result.

Comment: @NamanArora, glad to help! If the answer helped you, could you please mark it as correct? Thanks!